Замена стандартного размера превью изображения записи в Wordpress
По умолчанию вордпресс на превьюшку изображения записи во время редактирования или написания статьи устанавливает размер 'large':
const defaultSize = (0,external_wp_hooks_namespaceObject.applyFilters)('editor.PostFeaturedImage.imageSize', 'large', media.id, postId);

Если такого файла нет (в настройках указаны нулевые размеры), то берется изображение размером thumbnail и если нет и его, то оригинальный размер фотографии.
Добавил в functions.php свой размер
add_image_size( 'theme-thumbnail-image',  900, 300, true );

И через фильтр пытаюсь изменить стандартный размер превью изображения во время редактирования/создания статьи.
add_filter( 'block_editor_settings_all', 'my_block_editor_settings_all_filter', 10, 2 );

function my_block_editor_settings_all_filter( $editor_settings, $block_editor_context ){
    $editor_settings['imageDefaultSize'] = 'theme-thumbnail-image';
    return $editor_settings;
}

Но, т.к. у меня не создаются при загрузке изображения файлы размером large, то на превьюшке загружается thumbnail, но по логике должна была загрузиться с моим размером theme-thumbnail-image.

Но мой размер корректно создался

Отсюда вопрос, как мне изменить размер на превьюшке?

1."(в настройках указаны нулевые размеры), то берется изображение размером thumbnail и если нет и его" те ты удалил то что должно работать из коробки и пытаешься сделать тоже самое нагородив костылей? Отличный подход :) 2. "По умолчанию вордпресс на превьюшку изображения записи во время редактирования или написания статьи устанавливает размер 'large':" По умолчанию это зависит от темы.


Я не удалил то что должно работать из коробки, я убрал создание ненужного мне размера.
Объясню подробнее. Есть плагин Crop-Thumbnails, который позволяет сделать обрезку изображения произвольно. С размером large почему-то не дружит, если указать параметр large_crop = 0. Если large_crop = 1, то вордпресс обрезает и сохраняет не так как надо. Выход из этого - сделать свой отдельный размер, который нормально обрезается плагином. Я могу даже не удалять large. Мне нужно чтобы в превью был мой размер, а не large/thumbnail.
Фильтр $editor_settings['imageDefaultSize'] = мойразмер не срабатывает.



Возможно. Но это стандартное поведение вордпресса. Взято отсюда \wp-includes\js\dist\editor.js.

